# How to replace expression in a string with its value?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, parsefloat

Sorry if the question is worded badly, but what I'm trying to ask is, **How would you replace a substring of a string in JS with the product of two of the captured groups?** To see what I mean, look at the following line. How would I perform a task like the following:

```
expression.replace(regexp,parseFloat("$1")*parseFloat("$3"));
```

when "regexp" is `/(\d+(\.\d+)?)\*(\d+(\.\d+)?)/` and "expression" is `"20*5"`?

It doesn't work, and I'm not really sure why.  `expression.replace(regexp,"$1_$3")` prints out `20_5`, so **why would putting `"$1"` and `"$3"` in `parseFloat()` change their values from the values of the first and third groups to the strings `"$1"` and `"$3"`**?

If you're wondering, this is for the website [GraphWidget](http://graphwidget.co.nf) as a STEM project for PLTW class.

Thanks.

Comment: It's a string replace, what makes you think you can put numbers and parsing methods in there, and not just strings.

Comment: wouldn't eval("20*5") give you what you are looking for?

Comment: You need to pass a callback.

Comment: @Dalorzo yes eval would do it but i want to try it on my own.

Comment: @Slaks can you give me an example how please?

Comment: If you want to do it on your own, you have to write a parser and evaluator, just like the Javascript implementor did.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/wSGuZ/2/

Comment: @adeneo thanks. i don't really understand it, but I'll try it and try to understand how it works...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
"20*5".replace(
                 /(\d+(\.\d+)?)\*(\d+(\.\d+)?)/,
                 function (match, group1, group2, group3) { 
                   return parseFloat(group1)*parseFloat(group3) 
                 }
              );
```

See this doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference if you do this I think:

```
"20*5".split('*').reduce(function(a,c){ 
   return  a <=0? c : a*c 
 },0);
```

The advantage of this approach is that it will also work with `"20*5*3"` *without changing the code*

> **Disclaimer:** I understand you may want to use regular expressions to resolve your issue. I am just providing a side view of the problem.